# PHP - Stop attackers in using javascript in inputbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, htmlspecialchars

Like we use `htmlspecialchars` to avoid html tag as input.

Similarly, Is there any function or method that we can use to avoid javascript too.?

`htmlspecialchars` does not take care of script tag.

any suggestions. ?

Comment: you can use htmlentities().It prevents using all html tags

Comment: Also, please make sure to scrub the data on the server side as well, since attackers could submit data directly to the server and bypass the client-side protections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

Use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and the [FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) flag.

This will convert `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

```
$input = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fieldName', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

So this:

```
<script>alert('hello');</script>
```

Becomes this:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;hello&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

Take a look at the different sanitize filters. Instead of using fullspecialchars on everything, use the filter that applies to the input you're expecting... ex. if you're asking for a number, use a number filter.

Comment: I tried this: 
$str = "<script>alert('Hello');</script>";
$str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $str;
Output: alert('Hello');
Thats Ok however is there anyway I can use it as TRUE or FALSE... ?
if $str Contains html tags, it should exit and not enter details in DB.

Comment: Thanks, I could achieve, what I wanted to. Thank you again.

Comment: You could do something along the lines of `if($input != filter_var($input, ...)){ return false;}`

Answer (score 0):

It should take care of the script tags, as the `<` and `>` tags are translated.

`<` (less than) becomes `&lt;`

`>` (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

See the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php